# Instagram how to verify X-Hub-Signature in php

Tags: php

What's the right way to verify `X-Hub-Signature` in php?

I tried with

```
$xHubSignature = $request->getHeader('X-Hub-Signature');
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
$body = $request->getRawBody( );
$check = sha1('mysecret'.$postdata);
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 15):

```
hash_hmac( 'sha1', $postdata,'mysecret')
```

thanks to Payom Dousti

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/instagram-api-developers/7nKyipJENdI

Answer (score 9):

To verify `X-Hub-Signature` header sent by Instagram or [Facebook webhook callback](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks) in PHP version 5.6 or higher, you could use:

```
if ( hash_equals('sha1=' . hash_hmac('sha1', $postdata, 'mysecret'), 
                 $_SERVER['HTTP_X_HUB_SIGNATURE'] )
```

This is better than using `==` or `===` since `hash_equals` method would prevent *timing attacks*.